# problem with bluetooth audio while playing html 5 videos ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, video, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I've just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and I've encountering many problems. One of these is a strange behavior I think from pluseaudio. If i play a video from youtube in html5 using the standard audio output there are no problems. But if I try to play the same video switching to my logitech bluetooth audio bar, the video loads, but won't play. Any idea how I can resolve this?

many thanks, 
Valde_91

Comment: I've realized that the problem is not related only with html5 videos, but is general to every sound source on the computer (audio files, beeps, ... )

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by purging bluez:

```
sudo apt-get purge bluez*; sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then reinstalling it:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez
```